# Iterative RDD/Dataframe processing in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

My ADLA solution is being transitioned to Spark. I'm trying to find the right replacement for U-SQL [REDUCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/reduce-expression-u-sql?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) expression to enable:

1. Read logical partition and store information in a list/dictionary/vector or other data structure in memory
2. Apply logic that requires multiple iterations
3. Output results as additional columns together with the original data (the original rows might be partially eliminated or duplicated)

Example of possible task:

- Input dataset has sales and return transactions with their IDs and attributes
- The solution is supposed finding the most likely sale for each return
- Return transaction must happen after the sales transaction and be as similar to the sales transactions as possible (best **available** match)
- Return transaction must be linked to exactly one sales transaction; sales transaction could be linked to one or no return transaction - link is supposed to be captured in the new column `LinkedTransactionId`

The solution could be probably achieved by `groupByKey` command, but I'm failing identify how to apply the logic across multiple rows. All examples I've managed to find are some variation of in-line function (usually an aggregate - e.g. `.map(t => (t._1, t._2.sum))`) which doesn't require information about individual records from the same partition.

Can anyone share example of similar solution or point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution - feedbacks and suggestions for different approach or examples of iterative Spark/Scala solutions are greatly appreciated:

- Example will read Sales and Credit transactions for each customer (`CustomerId`) and process each customer as separate partition (outer `mapPartition` loop)
- Credit will be mapped to the sales with closest score (i.e. smallest score difference - using the `foreach` inner loop inside each partition)
- Mutable map `trnMap` is preventing double-assignmet of each transactions and captures updates from the process
- Results are outputted thru an `iterator` as into final dataset `dfOut2`

*Note: in this particular case the same result could have been achieved using windowing functions w/o using iterative solution, but the purpose is to test the iterative logic itself)*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD



case class Person(name: String, var age: Int)

case class SalesTransaction(
                      CustomerId : Int,
                      TransactionId : Int,
                      Score : Int,
                      Revenue : Double,
                      Type : String,
                      Credited : Double = 0.0,
                      LinkedTransactionId : Int = 0,
                      IsProcessed : Boolean = false
                      )

case class TransactionScore(
                           TransactionId : Int,
                           Score : Int
                           )

case class TransactionPair(
                          SalesId : Int,
                          CreditId : Int,
                          ScoreDiff : Int
                          )

object ExampleDataFramePartition{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Example Combiner")
      .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val df = Seq(
      (1, 1, 123, "Sales", 100),
      (1, 2, 122, "Credit", 100),
      (1, 3, 99, "Sales", 70),
      (1, 4, 101, "Sales", 77),
      (1, 5, 102, "Credit", 75),
      (1, 6, 98, "Sales", 71),
      (2, 7, 200, "Sales", 55),
      (2, 8, 220, "Sales", 55),
      (2, 9, 200, "Credit", 50),
      (2, 10, 205, "Sales", 50)
    ).toDF("CustomerId", "TransactionId", "TransactionAttributesScore", "TransactionType", "Revenue")
      .withColumn("Revenue", $"Revenue".cast(DoubleType))
      .repartition(2,$"CustomerId")

    df.show()


    val dfOut2 = df.mapPartitions(p => {

      println(p)


      val trnMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, SalesTransaction]()
      val trnSales = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[TransactionScore]
      val trnCredits = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[TransactionScore]
      val trnPairs = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[TransactionPair]


      p.foreach(row => {
        val trnKey: Int = row.getAs[Int]("TransactionId")
        val trnValue: SalesTransaction = new SalesTransaction(row.getAs("CustomerId")
          , trnKey
          , row.getAs("TransactionAttributesScore")
          , row.getAs("Revenue")
          , row.getAs("TransactionType")
        )

        trnMap += (trnKey -> trnValue)
        if(trnValue.Type == "Sales") {
          trnSales += new TransactionScore(trnKey, trnValue.Score)}
        else {
          trnCredits += new TransactionScore(trnKey, trnValue.Score)}
      })

      if(trnCredits.size > 0 && trnSales.size > 0) {
        //define transaction pairs
        trnCredits.foreach(cr => {
          trnSales.foreach(sl => {
            trnPairs += new TransactionPair(cr.TransactionId, sl.TransactionId, math.abs(cr.Score - sl.Score))
          })
        })
      }

      trnPairs.sortBy(t => t.ScoreDiff)
          .foreach(t => {
            if(!trnMap(t.CreditId).IsProcessed && !trnMap(t.SalesId).IsProcessed){
              trnMap(t.SalesId) = new SalesTransaction(trnMap(t.SalesId).CustomerId
                , trnMap(t.SalesId).TransactionId
                , trnMap(t.SalesId).Score
                , trnMap(t.SalesId).Revenue
                , trnMap(t.SalesId).Type
                , math.min(trnMap(t.CreditId).Revenue, trnMap(t.SalesId).Revenue)
                , t.CreditId
                , true
              )
              trnMap(t.CreditId) = new SalesTransaction(trnMap(t.CreditId).CustomerId
                , trnMap(t.CreditId).TransactionId
                , trnMap(t.CreditId).Score
                , trnMap(t.CreditId).Revenue
                , trnMap(t.CreditId).Type
                , math.min(trnMap(t.CreditId).Revenue, trnMap(t.SalesId).Revenue)
                , t.SalesId
                , true
              )              
            }
          })

      trnMap.map(m => m._2).toIterator

    })

    dfOut2.show()


    spark.stop()
  }
}
```